# How to insert the same html element twice?

Tags: javascript

Here's a part of my code

```
  elementol = document.createElement("ol");
  var longueur = titres.length;
  for ( k = 0; k &lt; longueur ; ++k) {
    elementli = document.createElement("li");
    elementli.appendChild(
      document.createTextNode(
        titres[k].firstChild.nodeValue
      )
    );
    elementol.appendChild(elementli);
  }
  body = document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0);
  body.appendChild(elementol);
```

The problem is If I try to find another Item and append, nothing work.
For example if I double the lines at the end to give something like :

```
  body = document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0);
  body.appendChild(elementol);
  body = document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0);
  body.appendChild(elementol);
```

Only  the first append work, not the second , so I don't have my result twice. I'm new with this language, and found some code, but I don't know how to add multiple value.

thanks

Answer (score 25):

A node can't be in two locations in the tree at once.

Use [`.cloneNode(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) for the second one to clone it.

```
document.body.appendChild(elementol);
document.body.appendChild(elementol.cloneNode(true));
```

The `true` argument makes it clone its descendants as well.

Comment: Great I understand that I can't read the same node twice, but how to read another node ? because I have the same problem if I try to read another node. ?

Comment: You mean the cloned one? Store it in a variable.

Comment: This solution is good, but the problem with it is that, if you clone the node with an image in it, it will request the request from the server again