# How to replicate HTML elements with Loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, function

I'm trying to replicate html elements with a javascript for loop, the loop runs fine but does not create new elements in html.

When i print father in console, Continued with 1 element only.

```js
var child = document.getElementById('child');
var father = document.getElementById('father');

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  father.appendChild(child)
}
```

```html
<div id="father">
  <div id="child" class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <h2 class="news" id="">News</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want print div child 5 times in the browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert the same html element twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203143/how-to-insert-the-same-html-element-twice)

Comment: (FYI, when someone formats your code and creates a snippet, please don't sabotage it again.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [.cloneNode](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp)

```js
var child = document.getElementById('child');
var father = document.getElementById('father');

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  father.appendChild(child.cloneNode(true))
}
```

```html
<div id="father">
  <div id="child" class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <h2 class="news" id="">News</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode):

```js
var child = document.getElementById('child');
var father = document.getElementById('father');

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    let childCopy = child.cloneNode(true);
    father.appendChild(childCopy);
}
```

```html
<div id="father">
    <div id="child" class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h2 class="news" id="">News</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `template` tag for cloning, the template tag is a mechanism for holding client-side content that is not to be rendered when a page is loaded but may subsequently be instantiated during runtime using JavaScript.

```js
var father = document.getElementById('father');
var temp = document.getElementsByTagName("template")[0];
  
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   father.appendChild(temp.content.cloneNode(true))
}
```

```html
  <template>
  
    <div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h2 class="news" id="">News</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

  </template>
  
  <div id="father">
```